# Probability of Knowing z Terms out of m

Tags: probability

This question is something I should know how to do, but with exams my brain is fried and I'm stuck.

Scenario:

A Professor gives his students $n$ Terms to know that may show up on the final exam. A student memorizes $k$ of these terms before the exam. Of these $n$ terms the professor selects $m$ of them uniformly at random to put on the test ($m > k$). What is a function that represents the probability that the student knows $z$ terms out of the $m$ selected by the professor ($z ≤ k$)?

Comment: Wait, is $m \leq k$ or $m > k$?

Comment: I corrected that last line to say z ≤ k. Sorry!

Comment: At any rate, this looks like a standard hypergeometric distribution.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem assuems the picks are independent and with all terms equally likely to be picked (in each of the student's choosing and the professor's choosing).
There are $\binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{m}$ ways to pick $k$ and $m$ terms respectively; that will be our denominator.

How do we get precisely $z$ matches?

We specify which $k$ of the $n$ terms the student chose -- $\binom{n}{k}$. For a given such choice we then specify which $z$ of those were the matches -- $\binom{k}{z}$. We finally specify which $(m-z)$ terms the professor selected that were *misses*, that is, that were among the $(n-k)$  terms the student punted -- $\binom{n-k}{m-z}$  A factor of $\binom{n}{k}$ appears in the numerator and in the denominator; these cancel leaving the answer

$$
f(z) = \frac{ \binom{k}{z} \binom{n-k}{m-z} }{\binom{n}{m}}
$$

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!